# Shiny application not loading with graphics

Tags: r, shiny, centos6, shiny-server

I have shiny app, which works perfectly fine on my local machine. I deployed the app on shiny-server running on `centos-release-6-9.el6.12.3.x86_64`. The content of the application is loaded without any graphics as shown below:

[image]

And I get the following message in JS consol.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://mamged:3838/v01/shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js”. v01:18:1
ReferenceError: Shiny is not defined[Learn More] v01:21:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://mamged:3838/v01/shinyjs/shinyjs-default-funcs.js”. v01:38:1
ReferenceError: shinyjs is not defined[Learn More] v01:39:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://mamged:3838/v01/message-handler.js”. v01:40:1
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined[Learn More]
    [Exception... "Favicon at "http://mamged:3838/favicon.ico" failed to load: Not Found." nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: resource:///modules/FaviconLoader.jsm :: onStopRequest :: line 156" data: no]
```

I am not sure what is going wrong.

**EDIT**

I have put some sample code to reproduce the example on the server.

**server.r**

```
# clear console
cat("\014")


# Defining the size of file to be accepted. -1 to accept any size.
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = -1) 


# Clear workspace environment
rm(list = ls())    

# set locale
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C') 

# main function
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

})
```

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


filenames <- list.files(path = "data",pattern="\\.txt$")
names(filenames) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.txt$", "", filenames)
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                  (navbarPage("MAMGEDCDE",
                              position = c("fixed-top"),
                              fluid = TRUE, selected = "none", 
                              navbarMenu("Help", icon = icon("fa fa-infocircle"),

                                         tabPanel(
                                           list(
                                             a("Reference Manual", 
                                               target="_blank", href = "MAMGEDManual.pdf"),

                                             a("GPLs Supported",
                                               target="_blank", href="gpl.pdf"),

                                             a("Video Tutorials",
                                               downloadLink("AbsoluteExpression", " Absolute Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                               downloadLink("DifferentialExpression", " Differential Expression", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                               )
                                             ))
                                         ),

                              navbarMenu("Sample Data",
                                         tabPanel(
                                           list(
                                             downloadLink("AffymetrixData", " Affymetrix", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                             downloadLink("CodelinkData", " Codelink", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                             downloadLink("IlluminaData", " Illumina", class=" fa fa-cloud-download")
                                             ))
                                         ),

                              navbarMenu("Stand-Alone Version", icon = icon("fa fa-infocircle"),
                                         tabPanel(
                                           list(
                                             downloadLink("CodeandData", " MAMGED", class=" fa fa-cloud-download"),
                                             a("Stand-alone Manual", target = "_blank", href= "Stand-alone.pdf")
                                             )
                                           )
                                         )
                              )
                   ),

                  br(),
                  br(),
                  useShinyjs(),  ## initialize shinyjs to reset input files.
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      br(),

                      width = 4,
                      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                                  tabPanel(id = "tab1", value = "tab1",
                                           h5("Upload Data Files"),
                                           br(),
                                           br(),

                                           fileInput("files", label = "Upload Data Files",
                                                     multiple = "TRUE",
                                                     accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,
                                                              text/plain', '.csv','.cel','.TXT','.txt', '.zip')),

                                           uiOutput('Display_source_data'),
                                           br(),

                                           textInput("mailid", "Enter Email ID", placeholder = "Enter your email id")
                                           ),

                                  tabPanel(id = "tab2", value= "tab2",
                                           h5("Download Data",style="bold"),
                                           br(),
                                           br(),
                                           br(),
                                           textInput("jobid", "Enter Job ID", placeholder = "Enter your job id")
                                           )),
                      br(),
                      br(),

                      tags$head(tags$script(src = "message-handler.js")),
                      fluidRow(
                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "input.tabs == 'tab1'",
                          column(4,
                                 actionButton("Submit", label = "Submit"))
                          ),
                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "input.tabs == 'tab2'",
                          br(),
                          column(4,
                                 uiOutput("button")
                                 )),

                        column(4,
                               actionButton("Reset_Input", label = "Reset"))
                        ),
                      br()

                      ),

                    mainPanel(
                      titlePanel(
                        headerPanel( 
                          h2( "Analysis of Microarray Gene Expression Data",
                              align="center", style="bold"
                              )
                          )
                        ),
                      h5("test page")
                      )
                    )
                  ))
```

It works fine on the local machine.

One more thing, do I need to install r packages by using `sudo -i R` to make it work. I installed all the packages without `sudo`.

Comment: any errors in the Shiny server log file?

Comment: @ginberg Now the application is not starting also and giving me `^[[32m[2017-02-03 17:23:56.841] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mError getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
^[[32m[2017-02-03 17:23:56.861] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mError getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.`

Comment: Did you check the application log file? This is by default located in /var/log/shiny-server directory. Run your application, and then check this directory for the most recent file. If they file has been deleted, depending on the version of Shiny Server you can add the following directive to the /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf file (it has to be at the top level):

preserve_logs true;

After restart of Shiny Server, access your application again, and check the log file. Usually there is useful information in the log file that could help you.

Comment: @ginberg I checked and latest information is `^[[32m[2017-02-06 19:13:41.893] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStopping listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
^[[32m[2017-02-06 19:13:41.894] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShutting down worker processes (with notification)
0^[[32m[2017-02-06 19:13:46.089] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShiny Server v1.4.2.786 (Node.js v0.10.40)
^[[32m[2017-02-06 19:13:46093] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing pidfile /var/run/shiny-server.pid`. Nothing more than this. I sometimes get `Favicon` error

Comment: You seem to be looking at the shiny server logfile only. The application logs contain probably more useful info. See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003717168-Shiny-Server-Error-Logs for the difference

Comment: @ginberg I have application on the following path `/srv/shiny-server/v01/`, but I don't see any log file there.

Comment: what about /var/log/shiny-server/*.log?

Comment: @ginberg Nothing other than `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:34103 Execution halted` but which is related to other application `"/var/log/shiny-server/hello-ibab-20170206-202412-34103.log"`.

Comment: In Firefox `ReferenceError: Shiny is not defined v01:21:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://mamged.ibab.ac.in:3838/v01/shinyjs/shinyjs-default-funcs.js”. v01:38:1
ReferenceError: shinyjs is not defined v01:39:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://mamged.ibab.ac.in:3838/v01/message-handler.js”. v01:40:1 [Exception... "Favicon at "http://mamged.ibab.ac.in:3838/favicon.ico" failed to load: Not Found."  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///modules/FaviconLoader.jsm :: onStopRequest :: line 156"  data: no]` in Firefox

Comment: In Google Chrome `(index):39 Uncaught ReferenceError: shinyjs is not defined
    at (index):39
(anonymous) @ (index):39
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://mamged.ibab.ac.in:3838/v01/font-awesome-5.3.1/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
K @ jquery.min.js:2
2(index):1 GET http://mamged.ibab.ac.in:3838/v01/font-awesome-5.3.1/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'Execution halted' is related to other application, could you elaborate? There's multiple apps running on your server or just one? It would also help if you can post your code or a reproducible example

Comment: When you install `shiny-server` it has some sample applications namely `hello`. The error is not related to my application `v01`. My code is working fine locally, and the problem on the server is that the graphics does not get loaded.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying.  So, no errors in the shiny-server. I am not totally sure, what's the problem than. Seeing the connection refused messages, it might be something with user permissions or firewall. Did you read the admin guide already? https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/

Comment: @AwaitedOne My recommendation is you provide access to the code that is creating the error, that or provide example code that exhibits the error you are encountering. Without a code example, it will be difficult to debug your situation.

Comment: @Technophobe01 Please follow the edit above

Comment: Have you tried determining if your images are deployed with your app and they are being referenced by an absolute path? img src="path to your graphic that is missing"?  I have no experience with shiny though, but I was thinking maybe worth a try.

Comment: @AwaitedOne, did you find a solution for this? The shared folder is inside the shiny package install path. I've given this dir 777 permissions, but it still fails to load properly. I ran out of ideas to try.

Comment: @Deleet, I can say It is giving me very tough time, unfortunately still to find the solution.

Comment: Thank you all, upgrading `shiny-server` to the latest version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your application is missing a package.
Check your application log by default located in 
`/var/log/shiny-server`. 
Also you can add the following option to your config file 
`/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`:

```
preserve_logs true; (at the top level)
```

After a restart of Shiny Server check your log file again.
Look for missing packages or libraries. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the configuration file, but I still see no error in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shiny-server is running as a special user.
Assume the username is like on other servers "www-data".
The problem now is that the files in the web-directory perhaps can be accessed by the shiny-server itself, but not by the clients.
**Long story short:** adjust the Unix-file-rights for all the files, so that a common client can access the files. This must be done for all files that shall be public available like images, css-files and js-files. Surely it can include any other files too you want to serve like PDF, Office-files, etc.
The unix-rights have to be `0744` for being readable, the last digit is for the public and in your case probably to change with `chmod`.
For a detailed explanation concerning `chmod` you can show the man-page on commandline with `man chmod`.

In some environments it's common that all "public" files are sorted in folders named "public" or "Public", then just the file-rights of these folders have to be changed recursive. Even for the public folders here I use plural, as there can be several folders always with the same name in different directories. On your server the `shared` folder seems having the same functionality but not all public files are sorted in it. If you prefer the folder name `shared` over `public`, you never have to change but only to adjust the rights accordingly.

The reason that I mentioned about the server-user "www-data" above is that the files in the web-directory should have this user as owner, but are not required to be public. All you r-files should be private excepted the files which should be called directly in the browser. So all the files are separated in public and private. The file-owner can be adjusted with `chown` which can be called on commandline recursive too and with `man chown` you also can show the detailed description.

About public r-files I don't know if they have to be executable on shiny-servers, **if so** then the file-rights for these files have to be `0755`.

**Update**
Also assure that all files are existent in your www-directory and that the domain is linked to the right folder.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think there is permission to read  `-rwxrwxr-x 1 Check.sh`
`-rw-rw-r-- 1 Job.sh`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab    counter.RData`
`drwxrwxrwx 2 ibab ibab   data`
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 ibab ibab     log.txt`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab  log_180202.txt`
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 ibab ibab    server.r`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab   server1.r`
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 ibab ibab   server_offline.R`
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 ibab ibab    server_offline1.R`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab timelog.txt`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab    ui.r`
`drwxr--r-- 2 ibab ibab    www'

Comment: check the permissions for the images and the javascipt files, probably they have to reside inside the folder www

Comment: All the files in `www` have read permission. `-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab   9919087 Apr 24  2018 Illumina Data.zip`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab 861877836 Apr 24  2018 MAMGED.zip`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab   3175927 Apr 24  2018 MAMGEDManual.pdf`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab    533932 Apr 24  2018 Stand-alone.pdf`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab       263 Apr 24  2018 all_sessions.R`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab    155438 Apr 24  2018 bootstrap.css`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab    184232 Apr 24  2018 gpl.pdf`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ibab ibab       174 Apr 24  2018 message-handler.js`

Comment: These files are missing in www: `v01/shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js`, `v01/shinyjs/shinyjs-default-funcs.js`, `v01/message-handler.js`.  Images are missing too. Perhaps you messed up somehow with your folder-hierarchy?

Comment: The files are in the `www` directory. I don't have any directory `shared` inside `v01`

Comment: `v01/shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js` is from your error-message, so there must be some fault with linking the documents and images, or you just have to provide the files on the paths where they are searched in the moment.

Comment: I don't have any `respond.min.js` and `shinyjs-default-funcs.js` files in the application. The same application was working fine previously with `3.4`.

Comment: Just control everything locally and and the same structure of folders and files must be on the server too. Also the domain-settings have to be correct concerning the www-folder (I'm not sure if you linked the domain to www or www/v01/). Then everything should work fine.

Comment: Yes domain is linked to `v01` and inside `v01` i have `www` directory.

Comment: Thats a fault probably. you general www-folder is "www" and for the domain then the subfolder "v01". No additional subfolder "www". That doesn't mean that it's not possible but it never seems being configured like that.

Comment: I think, `app -> (ui.r, server.r, www-> (bootstrap.css, or any other image, pdf)`

Comment: The files are searched by links starting with "http://mamged:3838/v01/" but you said you linked the domain to the folder v01, so the path had to be www/v01/v01/ and is not existent. Try linking the domain directly to www only and see if it's working.

Comment: Ya, sorry, `mamged` is the main folder in which all the shiny apps can be as `v01`

Comment: Ok, I don't see how I can help more. You've to check that links and filepaths are fitting to each other. That's you whole problem I think. It's also possible to adjust the links in the HTML perhaps. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your time.