# Uncaught ReferenceError: Shiny is not defined

Tags: r, shiny, centos, shiny-server

This question is related [application loading without css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995155/shiny-application-not-loading-with-graphics). I checked the java script console and get issues

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Shiny is not defined
    at (index):21

Uncaught ReferenceError: shinyjs is not defined
    at (index):39
```

The script at index 21 in source:

```
 `<script>Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('shinyjs-show', function(params) { shinyjs.debugMessage('shinyjs: calling function "show" with parameters:'); shinyjs.debugMessage(params); shinyjs.show(params);})`;
```

The application is running on shiny-server on CentOs 6.

Comment: How did you install the shiny package on your server?

Comment: @JohnCoene, typing `R` and then installing packages, not by `sudo -i R`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` somewhere within the session running the app.
Normally you would include this as part of the shiny UI.
But if the UI was created inside a package, then it might call `useShinyjs` when the package is built or installed and not in the session where the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably the issue (referring to your comment).

As indicated [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04), install your packages with:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

This is because your apps will be ran by a user called `shiny`, user which probably cannot access the package `shiny` because you installed it as another user.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it is not different, giving the same issue.

Comment: The error seems to be a bug as shown in the js code that shiny uses `<script>Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('shinyjs-show', function(params) { shinyjs.debugMessage('shinyjs: calling function "show" with parameters:'); shinyjs.debugMessage(params); shinyjs.show(params);});`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably, because you run the code before Shiny object is created by shiny. If you look at the code of shiny it have this:

```
$(function() {
  // Init Shiny a little later than document ready, so user code can
  // run first (i.e. to register bindings)
  setTimeout(initShiny, 1);
});
```

[init_shiny.js#L511](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/a2a4e40821b9811a40e461f67e3622196d8aa726/srcjs/init_shiny.js#L511)

you can use this function that I'm using:

```
var shinyReady = (function() {
  var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
  $(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callbacks.fire();
      callbacks = null;
    }, 100); // this probably can be 2 since shiny use 1
  });
  return function(callback) {
    if (callbacks) {
      callbacks.add(callback);
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  };
})();

shinyReady(function() {
   // your code that use Shiny object
});
```